# Why parameterMap is not calling in KendoGrid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

have the following kendo grid:

```
this.kGrid = $element.kendoGrid({
columns: [
    { field: 'Title' },
    { field: 'Description' },
    {
        field: 'StartDate',
        title: 'Start Date',
        template: `#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(DistributionDate), "${DATE_FORMAT} ${TIME_FORMAT}")#`,
    }
],
filterable: true,
dataSource: {
    type: 'aspnetmvc-ajax',
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/Pubs/GetPubs',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            data: () => ({
                collectionId: this.selectedCollection,
                categoryUid: this.selectedCategory
            })
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, type) {
            //i wawnt to add some logic here to convert StartDate from local time to UTC
        }
    },
    serverFiltering: true,
    schema: {
        data: 'Data',
        total: 'Total',
        model: {
            id: 'Uid',
            fields: {
                Title: { type: 'string' },
                Description: { type: 'string' },
                StartDate: { type: 'date' }
            }
        }
    }
}
}).data('kendoGrid');
```

So i have a grid with 3 columns and all of them are filterable. My goal is to convert the date in the filter for StartDate from local time to UTC. That's why i added **parameterMap** handler. But for some reason, parameterMap method is not called at all. What i'm doing wrong here?
Here is full code snippet - https://dojo.telerik.com/IqadArAn/3. But the problem is not reproducible here

EDIT: It seems that problem is in dataSource type, which is 'aspnetmvc-ajax'. If to change the dataSource type, parameterMap works.

Comment: can you provide example plase

Comment: If you add `console.log(data)` inside your parameter map does anything appear in your console?

Comment: @David, no, console is clear. Also tried to set a breakpoint inside of parameterMap, but it never triggered.

Comment: @dev_in_progress, what example do you want? I have an empty div on the page : `<div id="myCustomGrid"/>`. And $element equals to $("#myCustomGrid"). Provided source code just creates a kendoGrid inside this div.

Comment: @DenisKaminsky - Can you setup the `requestStart` event with the `e` parameter on the dataSource and do `console.log(e.sender)`?

Comment: I have tested the exact code snippet in an example and it appears that the parameterMap is called - https://dojo.telerik.com/IqadArAn

Comment: @CecoMilchev, forgot to mention that datasource.Type is 'aspnetmvc-ajax'

Comment: @CecoMilchev, here is full code snippet - https://dojo.telerik.com/IqadArAn/3. But the broblem is not reproducible here. In my case, parameterMap works only after removing "...DEFAULTS.dataGridSettings.dataSource"

Comment: The idea behind the different types in the data source is that they give you a predefined parameterMap and schema functions. Therefore, if the type is set, the parameterMap will come from the source and it will not honor the custom parameterMap function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative solution is to:

1. Skip setting the transport type
2. Implement custom read method

This questions describes the similar issue - https://www.telerik.com/forums/datasource-transport-function-mode-read-and-wrong-request-parameters.

Here is the code of custom **read** method, which should be placed inside of *dataSource.transport*.

```
read: (optionsData) => {
                            if (optionsData.data.filter) {
                                optionsData.data.filter.filters.forEach((item) => {
                                    if (item.field === "StartDate") {
                                        item.value = item.value.toISOString();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            var data = kendo.data.transports["aspnetmvc-ajax"].prototype.options.parameterMap.call({ options: { prefix: "" }}, optionsData.data, "read", false);
                            data.encryptedCollectionId = this.selectedCollection;
                            data.categoryUid = this.selectedCategory;

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: 'Pubs/GetPubs',
                                data: data
                            })
                            .then(
                                function succes(res) {
                                    optionsData.success(res);
                                },
                                function failure(res) {
                                    optionsData.error(res);
                                }
                            );
                        }
```